# Trouble while accessing to a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, this

I'm beginning to use jquery and Model View ViewModel and I encounter a problem with the utilisation of this with the Event Handler Attachment : on().
My first class is TicTacToeModel which manipulates a TicTacToe game in memory :

```
var TicTacToeModel = function () {
        Observable.call(this);
        this.grid = new Array(3);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.grid.length; ++i) {
            this.grid[i] = new Array(3);
        }
    };
//Some prototype function
//...
```

I have another class, TicTacToeController which depends on the first class and which manages the graphic part of the game with a manipulation of the DOM :

```
var TicTacToeController = function(game, selector) {
        this._element = $(selector);
        this._model = game;
        this._template = Handlebars.compile(view);
        this.addListeners();
        this.render();
    };
```

(declaration of game : `game = new TicTacToeModel();`)

So in my second class I have this function :

```
TicTacToeController.prototype.addListeners = function() {
    this._model.on('change', this.render, this);
    this._model.play(0,0);//works
    this._element.on('click', "td", function() {
        this._model.play(0,0);//doesn't work
    });
};
```

And I would like to call the play() function in the cell (0,0) (the function play updates the game in memory) when I click on the cell in my graphic interface but I cannot do it in the .on(). But that seems to be working outside of the .on() function so I suppose a bad utilisation of `this` causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like this.

Change this:

```
this._element.on('click', "td", function() {
    this._model.play(0,0);//doesn't work
});
```

to:

```
this._element.on('click', "td", function() {
    this._model.play(0,0); //should now work
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that works fine but if I add some jquery into the function like that : `TicTacToeController.prototype.addListeners = function() {
        this._model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this._element.on('click', "td", function() {
            $(this).addClass("case");
            $(this).html("X");
            this._model.play(0,0);//doesn't work
        }.bind(this));
    };` The jquery isn't be taken into account, have you got any idea to fix it ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "The jquery isn't be taken into account" but have you tried `$(this._element)...` instead of `$(this)...`?

Comment: `$(this._element)` doesn't work because it changes my whole grid but if I add the parameter "event" in: `this._element.on('click', "td", function(event) {...}`, event.target works. But  why I cannot use `$(this)` whereas it represents the "td" element of the .on() function ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the same scope, it's not the same this variable you are employing when calling the play method.
A dirty workaround could be

```
let _model = this._model
this._element.on('click', "td", function() {
        _model.play(0,0);//work!
    });
```

But as said it's a dirty workaround, maybe someone else could explain but basically think this produces a memory leak. Maybe the solution would be to use a method in the same class and pass the instance to the click method, kind of:

```
TicTacToeController.prototype.click = function() ...
...
this._element.on('click', "td", this.click);
```

Think this should do the trick, but I must admit I'm not a js expert.

Comment: I thought to use this dirty workaround too but I knew that there was a better way to solve my problem ^^.